# When I run my socket program, there get: `import: command not found`

Tags: python

I write a socket server programmer:

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
# Author:sele

import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 65432

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break

            conn.sendall(data)
```

when I run it in my command, there gets error:

> sele-MacBook-Pro:test01 ldl$  ./tests02-server.py
> ./tests02-server.py: line 5: import: command not found
> ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
> Error: Current platform "darwin 18" does not match expected platform "darwin 16"
> Error: If you upgraded your OS, please follow the migration instructions: https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration
> OS platform mismatch
> while executing
> "mportinit ui_options global_options global_variations"
> Error: /opt/local/bin/PORT: Failed to initialize MacPorts, OS platform mismatch
> ./tests02-server.py: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `('   ./tests02-server.py: line 10:` with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
> socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:'

why there can not find the `import`?

Comment: You are missing a ```#!/usr/bin/env python``` on the top of your ```tests02-server.py``` file.

Comment: Can you show us the exact command line that you are using to run your script? - oops..there it is at the top of the output.  Thanks @CarlNorum

Comment: @Steve - it's in the question already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running your program as a shell script, not a python program. Add an appropriate `#!` line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

to the top of your program, or run it explicitly from the command line:

```
$ python tests02-server.py
```

Comment: I don't believe you - can you show output from your attempt after making that change?

Comment: Yeah.  That should definitely have fixed the problem.  Make sure that your shebang (#!) line is the first line of the file.

Comment: From your edit, it does fix the problem with your original question. You just have python bugs now.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your new question is that you can't use `socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)` with `with`.  So that a `with` statement can clean up the resource it is working with, that resource's object has to have an `__exit__` method.  What `socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)` returns obviously has no `__exit__` method for `with` to call, hence this error.